# Network support for Optimism Sepolia and Optimism Mainnet for Safe wallets

Tags: safe-core-sdk, safe-core

gm, I am writing a script to interact with my Safe on Optimism Sepolia and I need to declare a `ContractNetworksConfig` object like this one:

```
 const contractNetworks: ContractNetworksConfig = {
        "10": {
            safeSingletonAddress: '0xB9A1ce9216B4247399a061c4Cf9aB0dc05C0C1C7',
            safeProxyFactoryAddress: '0x64d8DEDF5c125f9Fe718C339f4E026B846E0979A',
            multiSendAddress: '0x7D149Ce509865aBA06dc10d308CC1442CdDb7dA4',
            multiSendCallOnlyAddress: '0xBf1ab3C67DEC0dc4b490078898764C505fEc9296',
            signMessageLibAddress: '0xCBcd93E99a6F1e4070f924bb44E1c7F379Dce506',
            fallbackHandlerAddress: '0xd6b5aBB923Bac0609793a7D8387D49782EC6cbe6',
            createCallAddress: '0xB22D635D552eC95142E2Abe3FfB859eA7d7C0316',
            simulateTxAccessorAddress: '0x725dBa629570a34F41556540359B48b227C23963',
        }
    }
```

However, when I look at the [supported networks in the Safe docs](https://docs.safe.global/safe-smart-account/supported-networks), there are no valid deployments for Optimism Sepolia for either 1.4.1 or 1.3.0 (or any others for that matter). What next steps should I take?

Answer (score 0):

Optimism Sepolia is indeed not supported yet. You can either wait for our team to support it (no plans yet to do so) or deploy the core contracts by following our guidelines [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-smart-account#deployments).

Hope it helps! Louis